# server.address().address is not set when https.createServer() in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server

Simple as this:

Server.address().address is blank. Why is this? Where can I set it?

```
server = https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Listening on https://' + server.address().address + ':' + server.address().port);
});
```

which returns

> Listening on https://:::9804

`server.address()` returns

> { address: '::', family: 'IPv6', port: 9804 }

Comment: I think the `::` refer to the `0.0.0.0` in IPv4 mode

Comment: server.address().url

Comment: @ParitoshWalvekar Which will return `undefined`.

Comment: I  mentioned it for the restify module. My bad. Extremely sorry.

Comment: dont be extremely sorry @ParitoshWalvekar , this is actually a test run for a restify setup so that will come in handy ;)

Comment: from https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/9195

> It's dual stack by default, hence why you see the ::ffff:127.0.0.1. which is why it shows ipv6 etc.